# How to convert my list<> data to below class?

Tags: c#, json

This is my data:

```
"User_Name": "Murali",
        "Data": [
          {
            "User_Name": "Murali",
            "Sno": 1,
            "ID": 2989,
            "Passport": "yes",
            "Address": "india"
          },
          {
            "User_Name": "Murali",
            "Sno": 2,
            "ID": 2998,
            "Passport": "yes",
            "Address1": "singapore",
                  },
```

and I want to convert to :

```
public class MontModel
{
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public MontModel MontModel { get; set; }
    public int Sno { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string passport { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Its json data, you can use - [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: var result = model
                .GroupBy(s => new { s.User_Name })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Data = x.Select(j => new
                    {
                        j.Sno,
                        j.ID,
                        j.User_Name,
                        j.Address1,j.passport 
                    }).ToList()
                });
i tried above one like but i didn't get i convert my jsondata to listview then i want like above mentoned class

Comment: Are you open to directly storing the json source data first as a class, and then converting it to your desired RootObject class?

Comment: yes like that i convert   i want this data                                                                                                    [{"MontModel1":{"User_Name":"Murali"},"Sno": 1,"ID":2989,"User_Name":"Murali","Passport":"Yes","Address":"India"}]